# Naming convention for database change scripts?

Tags: database, naming-conventions, change-script

I plan on using a "base script" for my initial database version 1.0.0 but after that I will require change scripts which "upgrade" the database to newer versions. I'm not sure how to name these scripts in my repository.

I was envisioning something along the lines of:

- Baseline-6.0.0.sql
- Patch-6.0.1.sql
- Patch-6.0.2.sql
- Patch-6.1.0.sql

What is a good naming convention to use and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails uses [timestamped migration files](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html). Each file starts off with a database-style timestamp followed by a short description: `20080717013526_your_migration_name.rb`. This ensures they show up in order and give you information about what the migration actually does. It's just one approach, but I think it works well.

Comment: What would be an example of a migration name?

Comment: `add_client_id_to_projects`, `create_products_table` for example.